# calling stored procedure in a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have created a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure which finds dependent objects on a particular table.

I want to run this stored procedure for different database and for different tables. I have created cursor for this.

When I write `USE @dbname`, it tries to find the stored procedure in a @dbname and not the current database.

Can anybody please help me with how do I write this command in a cursor?

```
DECLARE name_cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT db_name, obj_name from Stats_Usage 
    WHERE last_user_update > '2011-06-01' ORDER BY db_name 
DECLARE @tableName NVARCHAR (800)
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(800)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(900)
OPEN name_cur
FETCH name_cur INTO @dbName, @tableName 
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN 

SET @sql = 'USE '+@dbName +' EXEC proc_depend ' + @tableName
EXEC (@sql)
FETCH name_cur INTO @dbName, @tableName
END
CLOSE name_cur
DEALLOCATE name_cur
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [fully qualify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879.aspx) your Stored Procedure name.

Assuming the database your SP resides in is called `procs` (for example), you could amend your query to use the following:

```
SET @sql = 'USE '+@dbName +' EXEC procs.dbo.proc_depend ' + @tableName
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Yes it worked!! I am creating a table in a stored procedure I have written. But when I call it from the above query, it returns an error saying that table already exists. When we run a stored procedure, does the table gets created? I am confused.

Comment: But does it really matter for the execution of the procedure which database is current? I thought all the objects the SP references are considered to be in the same database as the SP, unless they are explicitly qualified with a different database name.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your stored proc to check for dependant objects cross database. You'll want to send it a command like this:

```
  exec proc_depend 'MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable';
```

Try this instead:

```
 SET @sql = ' EXEC proc_depend ''' @dbName + '.dbo.'+ @tableName + ''';
```

You'll need to dig into & modify `proc_depend` to ensure that it can take a fully qualified object name like `database.schema.table`

Comment: @anjali: likely you would. You may need to send a string to your proc.